# open() function error when flags are a char string pointer instead of an int

Tags: c, unix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>  
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int i=1;
    for(i=1;i<argc;++i)
    {
        char temp;
        fd=open(argv[i],"O_RDWR"); 
        if (fd==-1)
            perror("file:");
        while (read(fd,&temp,1)!=EOF)
        {
            putchar(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

I execute `./a.out a b`. `a` and `b` are files in  my directory. I get an error saying `File exists`.
The line `open(argv[i],"O_RDWR")` is not opening the file.

It is returning `-1` since the file exists . How then should i open the file using the `open` system call?

Comment: If you had compiled with warnings turned on you would certainly have got one for this program.

Comment: The flags arguments are a bunch of bits, represented in an unsigned integer. Who knows what nonsensical flags got passed...

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> fd=open(argv[i],"O_RDWR");
>                 ^      ^
> ```

You're passing a `char *` instead of an integer constant. Drop the `"`, it should be just:

```
fd = open(argv[i], O_RDWR);
```

---

Interestingly but likely off-topic, `open` must have thought you passed `O_CREAT | O_EXCL`, that's why it complained about the file already existing.

---

> So what i have wriiten is right then???But the code is going into an
>   infinite look printing nothin

The function `read(2)` doesn't return `EOF` at and of input but rather `0`.

Comment: Ok...thanks...One more thing whats the second arguenent of read??The man page says it is void *buf...I dont understand

Comment: @Nikhil It's a buffer where `read(2)` will store the stuff it reads. It must be prepared to hold at least the amount specified by the third  argument to `read`.

Comment: So what i have wriiten is right then???But the code is going into an infinite look printing nothin

Comment: Oh ..k..k...Thanks a lot...Just 1 more clarification..At the end of file temp will have EOF character right?

Comment: @Nikhil There is no EOF character on Unix. The file ends where the inode says it ends.